# An elementary question about real plane metrics

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Given the metric $d_p$ on the real plane, i.e.,

$ d_p(x,y)=[|x_1-y_1|^p+|x_2-y_2|^p]^{1/p}$

For which values of $p \geq 1$ is it true that the following set
is the usual line segment in the real plane between points $x$ and $y$:

$\{z \in \mathbb{R}^2 | d_p(x,z) + d_p(z,y) = d_p(x,y)\}$

More generally what could be said about metrics for which this is true ?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

this need the $d_p(x,0)=\|x\|$ defined a norma and this norma to
be Euclidean ie verified the paralelogramme identity
$\|x+y\|^2+\|\|x-y\|^2=2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)$ so required $p$ an even
number